# why are zfs on linux transfer rtates reported incorrectly after expanding array?

Tags: raid, storage, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have upgraded the drives in a 4 drive Raidz array in a NAS server and the array has auto expanded to the new size. In testing transfer rates from the NAS server now I observe that when performing large read transfers the performance is poor, struggling to get above 10MB/s although iotop and zpool iostat can report very high numbers up to 500MB/s What could be leading to this strange behaviour? As I have been upgrading the array I can also observe that it performs the same whether there are 4 devices online or degraded to 3.

The server is connected with a single gigabit network connection and can saturate it with a single drive using ext4

Comment: 10MB/s suggests 100Mbit network connectivity. You have not given any details about how you make the test and how you are connected to the nas.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's on a single gigabit connection, but that still doesn't explain how iostat reports far higher rates than is actually happening.

Comment: Are you sure the pool isn't currently performing a scrub or rebuild? Do 'zpool status -v' to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I as I had been experimenting with cache settings to see what would happen I had left the primary cache switched off which can result in real IO being far greater than logical IO due to

> [application] reads a file, gets 4k (pagesize?) of data and processes it, then it reads the next 4k, etc.
>
> ZFS, however, cannot read just 4k. It reads 128k (recordsize) by default. Since there is no cache (you've turned it off) the rest of the data is thrown away.
>
> 128k / 4k = 32
>
> 32 x 2.44GB = 78.08GB

from [FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/zfs-primarycache-all-versus-metadata.45555/#post-254481)